# Permissions problem on mounting afp drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, afp

I am trying to mount a network drive via AFP on an Ubuntu 10.04 server machine. After installing AFP support, I use the following command:

```
sudo mount_afp afp://USER:PASS@afp.host.com/directory/ /media/dir
```

This seems to work and it tells me that mounting succeeded. However, when I navigate to /media/dir I get the following error:

```
cd: cfs: Input/output error
```

Permissions in /media are:

```
d?????????  ? ?              ?                ? dir/
drwx------ 12 user        4.0K 2010-10-25 16:08 otherdisk/
```

So there is a permissions problem here. I eventually want to mount this drive automatically using fstab. What do I need to do to make the disk accessible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the directory was created with a non-root user.

I also recommend uncommenting the `user_allow_other` line in `/etc/fuse.conf`, and then adding an entry in /etc/fstab that mounts it as the user that will need to access it (though the group must be `fuse`), like so:

`afpfs#afp://USER:PASS@afp.host.com/directory/ /media/dir fuse user=USER,group=fuse 0 0`

Now you should be able to do `sudo mount /media/dir` and be able to access it.