# How to backup an HFS+ partition using Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, mac, apple

i need to mount via AFP an HFS+ partition (Mac) and Backup it to an external drive,  using Ubuntu. 
The problem is that in Nautilus i can 'view' the drive using afp:\myserver_ip but when i launch a backup tool, like gRsync or LuckyBackup or anyothers, i can't view the partition!

How to do ?

Answer (score 1):

See [this link on mounting AFP shares in ubuntu.](https://serverfault.com/questions/197147/permissions-problem-on-mounting-afp-drive)  Your backup programs don't "see" the share because it's not presented to them as a (local) filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

can you read the content? if so your best option is going to be to use `rsync` to create your backups across the network.

Most likely gRsync && LuckyBackup have an internal restriction on what filesystems they will support, try a simply rsync such as: `rsync -gioprtuv --progress /path/to/hfs /path/to/mounted/afp/share` and see how you get on. All being well you can then use a simple bash script to kick off an incremental copy, if you want to instead provide retentive and separate backups explore the `rsync --backup` options.